# Mongodb transform array using aggregation

Tags: arrays, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have an array in Mongodb collection:

```
some_array:
    0: title: "Community"
       model: "A"
    1: title: "News"
       model: "B"
```

How can I get only titles of array and list them as bellow:

```
titles: "Community, News"
```

Comment: does the answer help you?

Answer (score 1):

You can group by `null` means group all titles and then project titles array only

Working [Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/AePMwpnclPm)

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": null,
      "titles": {
        "$push": "$title"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      _id: 0,
      titles: {
        "$reduce": {
          "input": "$titles",
          "initialValue": "",
          "in": {
            "$cond": {
            "if": { "$eq": [ { "$indexOfArray": [ "$titles", "$$this" ] }, 0 ] },
            "then": { "$concat": [ "$$value", "$$this" ] },
            "else": { "$concat": [ "$$value", ", ", "$$this" ] }
          } 
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $project: {
      titles: "$somearray.title"
    }
  }
])
```

**Working [Mongo playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/Dkt_KXFQ1wI)**